# In R, read files from folder in a list and assign list element names by the file names w/o file format (.fa)

Tags: r, lapply

I´m making a `list` of `fasta` files and read them from a folder. The file name should be assigned as `list element` name w/o the `.fa` file format.

I´m using `list.files` to asses the files in the directory `"Folder"`

```
filenames <- list.files("Folder",pattern = ".fa",full.names = T)
```

and than read the fasta files in.

```
list <- lapply(filenames, FUN=readDNAStringSet, use.names=T, format="fasta")
```

I found this code using `setNames` to define the `list` element name.

```
list<- setNames(list, substr(list.files("Folder", pattern=".fa"), 1,15 ))
```

But my file names have different length (makes it difficult to use the START to STOP (`,1, 15`)) and for further processing I would like to get rid of the `.fa`

The files would look like:

```
Gene1.fa
Gene12.fa
Gene22a.fa
Gene123abc.fa
```

I´m using `DECIPHER` but I guess this is a more base R question?

Comment: You can use `sub("\\.fa", "", v1)`

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Is it to use like `sub("\\.fa", "", list)` in my case?

Comment: I think it is the `list.files` instead of the `list` (which is a output of `readDNAStringSet`.  I meant instead of `substr(`, you may need `sub("\\.fa", "", list.files("Folder", pattern = "\\.fa"))`

Comment: Thanks! that works fine! And you are right, I should call it `mylist` not `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to remove the substring at the end, we could use `substr` as well, but make sure to index the first/last from the end instead from the beginning as it is varying

```
v1 <- list.files("Folder", pattern=".fa")
substring(v1, first  = 1, last = nchar(v1) -3)
#[1] "Gene1"      "Gene12"     "Gene22a"    "Gene123abc"
```

---

Or another option is `sub` to match the dot (`.` - metacharacter that matches for any character, so escape (`\\`) it to get the literal meaning) followed by 'fa' at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\.fa$", "", v1)
```